# how to implement react router protectedRoute with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm trying to implement **PrivateRoute** but it never redirects.
i tried everything even commenting returning `<Component />` part but it still return the component !!!!

[image: this is redux state data after logging out]

[image: this is the data i logged inside my private route component]

my PrivateRouter component:

i'm trying to get {isLoggedIn} from redux state

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  render,
  accessType,
  ...rest
}) {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { last_role_type: userType } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("router auth: ", auth);
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth.isLoggedIn ? (
          Component ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            render(props)
          )
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

my router code:

```
<Router>
<Provider store={store}>
  <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={4} hideIconVariant={false}>
    <Header>
      <CustomSnackbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/register">
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/assessment/create">
          <AssessmentForm />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/assessment">
          <Assessment />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/not-found">
          <NotFound />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/not-found" />
      </Switch>
    </Header>
  </SnackbarProvider>
</Provider>
</Router>
```

even after commenting it still is returning the component instead of redirecting:

```
return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
         auth.isLoggedIn ? (
        //   Component ? (
             <Component {...props} />
        //   ) : (
        //     render(props)
        //   )
         ) : (
          <Redirect to="/enterPhone" />
         )
      }
    />
  );
```

Comment: if you put `[isLoggedIn]` for the dependency array of your `useEffect` does it log the expected value after the initial value of undefined?

Comment: `auth` looks like an object, so I think it should be destructured, i.e. `const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);`.

Comment: i think it does,  because when i change the code it hot reloads and logs the data

Comment: Drew it's not the case, i was making the changes when i posted the question, it will not return the whole object

Comment: You can see in the second image the `isLoggedIn` value is an object with just the `token` key/value. If you are making changes then please keep the code snippets and related images in your question in sync.